hadoop datanode error hostname contains invalid characters. Fixed
When I execute start-dfs.sh first time, there is a error about datanode. The log likes:
Starting namenodes on [hadoop01]
Starting datanodes
: hostname contains invalid characters
: hostname contains invalid characters
: hostname contains invalid characters
Starting secondary namenodes [hadoop03]

Hadoop version is V3.1.3
OS: 112~20.04.1-Ubuntu

I found what the problem is. It's the configuration file workers accelerate the problem. So, fix the file $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/workers, which can start datanode right now.

How to fix workers? I met the same problem.

Fixed it. Create the workers file in Linux System, Not in Windws

When I encountered this issue, I found that I instead can start the datanode this way:
sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode


Yes, the command start datanode. But it's not a convenient way

I met the same problem. This command can only add the data nodes one by one.

Fixed it. Create the workers file in Linux System, Not in Windws
